# Implement a Function as a Column in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, numpy

I have a school project where I need to create a table which shows what a specific customer bought and how much.

Here is the table that I have right now:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVfOO.png)

How can I implement a `Discount` column? The discount needs to be calculated in a function.

The discount works like this:

- If "Menge" is over 12 the Discount is 1
- If "Menge" is over 24 the Discount is 3

Basically like this:

[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTglI.png)

Here is the code I already have.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
bestellungen = pd.read_csv ('bestellungen.csv', sep = ';', index_col = 0)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
kunden = pd.read_csv ('kunden.csv', sep = ';', index_col = 0)


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rabattstaffel = pd.read_csv ('rabattstaffel.csv', sep = ';', index_col = 0)

#Menge Darstellen

bestellungensum = bestellungen.sum(axis=1)

bestellungen = bestellungen.assign(Menge = bestellungensum)
print(bestellungen)

#Rabattfunktion 

def Rabatt(row):
  if Rabatt["Menge"] > 12: 
    return 1
  elif ["Menge"] > 24: 
    return 3

new_column = bestellungen.apply(Rabatt, axis=1)  # axis here defines whether the function is applied to rows or columns.
# new_column is a series containing your values for the rabatt column

data["Rabatt"] = new_column
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; "It would be nice if someone could help me here." is [not something we can answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). What is your **question**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems.

First problem: I needed to change the order of code form

```
if Rabatt["Menge"] > 12: 
    return 1
  elif ["Menge"] > 24: 
    return 3
```

to

```
def Rabatt(bestellungensum):
    if bestellungensum >= 24: 
        return 3
    elif bestellungensum >= 12: 
        return 1
    elif bestellungensum < 12: 
        return 0
```

the second would never fire off, because if the first condition matches, it does not continue to check.

Also I needed to add a line for the zeros otherwise it would say NaN in the Dataframe

Second Problem: The Data.apply command was wrong and the parameters.

`bestellungen['Rabatt'] = bestellungen['Menge'].apply(Rabatt)`

This here is the right one.

```
def Rabatt(bestellungensum):
    if bestellungensum >= 24: 
        return 3
    elif bestellungensum >= 12: 
        return 1
    elif bestellungensum < 12: 
        return 0

bestellungen['Rabatt'] = bestellungen['Menge'].apply(Rabatt)

print(bestellungen)
```

Here is the correct code all together.